# The Jensen gap $\mathbb{E}[|\overline X|] - |\mu|$

Tags: probability, average, jensen-inequality

Let $ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with finite mean $ \mu $ and variance $ \sigma^2 $. Let $ \overline X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i $ denote the sample average. I would like to bound the Jensen gap $ \mathbb{E}[|\overline X|] - |\mu| $ for $ \mu \neq 0 $. Simulations suggest that the gap decays exponentially in $ n $, which indeed can be verified asymptotically by the central limit theorem. But I would like an analogous bound that is valid for all $ n $. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The argument is subtle. Asymptotically, the gap is approximately $ \mathbb{E}[|Z|] - |\mu| $, where $ Z $ is normal with mean $ \mu $ and variance $ \sigma^2/n $. Using the formula for the mean of a folded normal random variable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution), we get $ \mathbb{E}[|Z|] - |\mu|  = (\sigma/\sqrt{n})\sqrt{2/\pi}e^{-n\mu^2/(2\sigma^2)} - 2\mu(1-\Phi(\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma)) $, assuming $ \mu > 0 $. Using Mills' ratio $ 1-\Phi(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{x}(1+O(1/x^2)) $ for large $ x $, you can show that this bound decays exponentially.

Comment: So $ \mathbb{E}[|Z|] - |\mu| = O(\frac{\sigma^3}{n^{3/2}\mu^2}e^{-n\mu^2/(2\sigma^2)}) $.

Comment: I significantly misunderstood your question initially, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries! I probably didn't ask it in the best way...

Answer (score 1):

By the reverse triangle inequality and Jensen's inequality:
$$
|E(|\bar X| - |\mu|)| 
\le E(|\bar X - \mu|)
= E\left(\sqrt{(\bar X - \mu)^2}\right)
\le \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)}
=
\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}
$$
where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X_1$.

I suspect it is a misstep to assume that the asymptotic you get from a normal distribution will be representative of what happens in general. The asymptotic for $E(|\bar X|)$ might depend on information in the tail behavior of the $X_i$'s, which is information you lose when you apply the CLT heuristic. The following `R` code suggests that you get polynomial decay when $X_i$ has a $t$-distribution:

```
mysim <- function(n, reps) {
  moo <- matrix(rt(n = n * reps, df = 4, ncp = 0), nrow = n)
  return(mean(abs(colMeans(moo))))
}

q <- sapply(100:200, function(n) mysim(n, 10000))
plot(q)
```

Comment: It's important that the mean $ \mu $ is nonzero. If you rerun your code with, say $ \mu = 1 $, you get a much faster rate of convergence.